# Convert .kv to custom python class

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm new to Kivy and having a hard time understanding why my code isn't working.

I'd like to convert some reusable Kv language code into a custom python class but I can't figure out why it's not working.

```
<ReceivingShipmentDetailScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20
        spacing: 15

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50

            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (0.1803921568627451, 0.20784313725490197, 0.24313725490196078, 1)
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            Label:
                text: 'Receive New Shipment'
                bold: True
                font_size: 20
```

I attempted to create a python class and pass in `page_header_text` when it's called in my Kv code but it doesn't seem to be working.

The text reads "Title" instead of the expected "Receive New Shipment". Also the format is messed up; the label and rectangle are in separate parts of the page. It seems that `CustomLayout` also doesn't have a parent widget and the size is different than expected.

```
class CustomLayout(BoxLayout):
    page_header_text = StringProperty('Title')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.padding = 20
        self.spacing = 15

        page_header = BoxLayout(
            size_hint_y=None,
            height=50,
        )
        with page_header.canvas.before:
            Color(
                0.1803921568627451,
                0.20784313725490197,
                0.24313725490196078,
                1,
            )
            Rectangle(pos=page_header.pos, size=page_header.size)

        page_header.add_widget(Label(
            text=self.page_header_text,
            bold=True,
            font_size=20,
        ))

        self.add_widget(page_header)
```

Here's my usage the usage in the .kv file.

```
<ReceivingShipmentDetailScreen>:
    CustomLayout:
        page_header_text: 'Receive New Shipment'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color , Rectangle
from kivy.clock import Clock

class CustomLayout(BoxLayout):  
    page_header_text = StringProperty('Title')
    spacing = 15
    padding = 20,20,20,20
    orientation = 'vertical'

    def func(self, *args):
        with self.page_header.canvas.before:
            Color(
                0.1803921568627451,
                0.20784313725490197,
                0.24313725490196078,
                1,
            )
            Rectangle(pos=self.page_header.pos, size=self.page_header.size)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.page_header = BoxLayout(
            size_hint_y=None,
            height=50,
        )
        self.page_header.add_widget(Label(
            text=self.page_header_text,
            bold=True,
            font_size=20,
        ))

        self.add_widget(self.page_header)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.func,0)

class WindowApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return CustomLayout()

WindowApp().run()
```

or

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
kv = '''

<CustomLayout>:
    spacing:15
    padding:20,20,20,20
    orientation:'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.1803921568627451, 0.20784313725490197, 0.24313725490196078, 1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        Label:
            text: root.page_header_text
            bold: True
            font_size: 20
    
'''

class CustomLayout(BoxLayout):
    page_header_text = StringProperty('Title')


class WindowApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return CustomLayout()

WindowApp().run()
```